# Redirect to MVC action through jQuery without having to reference the folder it is in?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I was able to successfully redirect to MVC action through jQuery unless I changed my root. Before it was `localHost`, now it is `localHost/App`. Before I was redirecting like this:

```
window.location.href = '/MyController/MyView/' + MyParameter;
```

Now, I need to change it to:

```
window.location.href = 'App/MyController/MyView/' + MyParameter;
```

I don't want to do like this because later on I might need to move it to some other folder. How do I redirect to a URL without having to reference the folder it is in?

Comment: Is this jQuery script in separate js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Url.RouteUrl` to help make the first bits, or another command in `@Url` e.g `@Url.Action`, they can make the url bit.

Does that help?

So

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller",new {id = null})/' + MyParameter;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: You mean something like this: `@Url.Action("View","Controller", new{ MyParameter })` But how would I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, but don't add the My Paremter bit. But are you in a .js file?

Comment: No. I am in my View. Currently, my code is spaghetti. Razor Syntax and JS in same view.

Comment: Yeah so @Url("View","Controller") should do, sometimes you need to null an id or something so @Url("View","Controller", new {id = null})

Comment: There should be "/" before parameter.